# Is GoDaddy SSL standard certificate compatible with all browsers?

Tags: godaddy, security-certificate

Could you answer to at least one of these questions:

1. Is GoDaddy SSL standard certificate compatible with *all* browsers
   (Chrome and Safari on iPhone, or Android browsers included)?

   http://www.godaddy.com/ssl/ssl-certificates.aspx?ci=8979
2. Is it running on Apache servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Yes

:)

I use it for all of my clients' websites which are hosted on an Apache powered web server. I obviously wouldn't do that if it wasn't 100% compatible.

Comment: Same, never had a problem except for the usual GoDaddy upsell junk.

Comment: As mentioned in my own answer, this is simply wrong. There are many old web browsers which do not contain the GoDaddy root certificate.

Answer (score 5):

No, it is certainly *not* compatible with all browsers, but you'll probably never encounter one that doesn't support it.

GoDaddy have a [web page](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/1139/which-browsers-and-devices-are-your-ssl-certificates-compatible-with) listing their compatibility. Notable exceptions include:

- Internet Explorer before V5.01
- Netscape before V4.7
- Opera before V7.5
- Safari for Mac OS X before 10.3.4
- Palm OS before V6.1

Comment: Fact: IE1 didnt support https at all!

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/681234

As per the link above, it is not compatible with all browsers in Mac (11.4) and iPhone (14.6)

Comment: That link being now 1 year old, so things may probably have changed since then.

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is compatible for all browsers.

Comment: Can you provide a source for this answer?

Answer (score -3):

Yes    all browsers but not versions.

Comment: Are there any references for this? I do not doubt you- and I realize that the question is essentially a Yes / No question, but it may be important to point to some helpful resources. It may be useful to know which versions of what browsers.Thanks in advance!!